# C# XDocument get all images from XML and show them in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xml, linq, binding, datacontext

I have a problem where im trying to get all the "thumb" image links out of the XML, and then show them in a LongListSelector.

Here is my LongListSelector code:

```
<phone:LongListSelector LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="180,180" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="5">
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Images}"></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
```

and my DataContext:

```
this.DataContext = gd.GetGameItems;
```

The code to read the xml and to store data:

```
var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var gameData = feedXml.Root.Descendants("Game").Select(x => new GetGame
            {
                ID = (int)x.Element("id"),
                GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
                Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform"),
                ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
                Images = new Uri(GetImages(x)),
            })
              .ToList();
            foreach (var item in gameData) GetGameItems.Add(item);

private ObservableCollection<GetGame> _GetGameItems = new ObservableCollection<GetGame>();
    public ObservableCollection<GetGame> GetGameItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this._GetGameItems;
        }
    }

public class GetGame
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }        
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public Uri Images { get; set; }
}
```

This is where im trying to get all the images from, right now i can only get from one image link:

```
 private static string GetImages(XElement gameNode)
    {
        return "http://thegamesdb.net/banners/" + (string)gameNode.Descendants("boxart")
                               .FirstOrDefault().Attribute("thumb");
    }
```

Here is the XML:

```
    <Data>
  <baseImgUrl>http://thegamesdb.net/banners/</baseImgUrl>
  <Game>
    <id>2</id>
    <GameTitle>Crysis</GameTitle>
     <PlatformId>1</PlatformId>
     <Platform>PC</Platform>
     <ReleaseDate>11/13/2007</ReleaseDate>
     <Overview>
     From the makers of Far Cry, Crysis offers FPS fans the best-looking, most highly-        evolving gameplay, requiring the player to use adaptive tactics and total customization of    weapons and armor to survive in dynamic, hostile environments including Zero-G. Earth, 2019. A team of US scientists makes a frightening discovery on an island in the South China Sea. All contact with the team is lost when the North Korean Government quickly seals off the area. The United States responds by dispatching an elite team of Delta Force Operators to recon the situation. As tension rises between the two nations, a massive alien ship reveals itself in the middle of the island. The ship generates an immense force sphere that freezes a vast portion of the island and drastically alters the global weather system. Now the US and North Korea must join forces to battle the alien menace. With hope rapidly fading, you must fight epic battles through tropical jungle, frozen landscapes, and finally into the heart of the alien ship itself for the ultimate Zero G showdown.
    </Overview>
<ESRB>M - Mature</ESRB>
<Genres>
<genre>Shooter</genre>
</Genres>
<Players>4+</Players>
<Co-op>No</Co-op>
<Youtube>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3vO01xQ-DM</Youtube>
<Publisher>Electronic Arts</Publisher>
<Developer>Crytek</Developer>
<Rating>8.1111</Rating>
<Images>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-1.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-1.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-2.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-2.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-3.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-3.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-4.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-4.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-5.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-5.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">fanart/original/2-6.jpg</original>
    <thumb>fanart/thumb/2-6.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <boxart side="back" width="1525" height="2162" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/back/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/back/2-1.jpg</boxart>
  <boxart side="front" width="1525" height="2160" thumb="boxart/thumb/original/front/2-1.jpg">boxart/original/front/2-1.jpg</boxart>
  <banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g2.jpg</banner>
  <banner width="760" height="140">graphical/2-g3.jpg</banner>
  <screenshot>
    <original width="1920" height="1080">screenshots/2-1.jpg</original>
    <thumb>screenshots/thumb/2-1.jpg</thumb>
  </screenshot>
  <clearlogo width="400" height="95">clearlogo/2.png</clearlogo>
</Images>
</Game>
</Data>
```

I hope there is someone that can help.

Comment: You haven't said what happens with your current code, nor shown an example of the XML involved.

Comment: Sorry i added the XML now. The problem is i dont know how to collect all the image links, because i can't get it to work with a list. I hope this explains it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for?

```
private static IEnumerable<Uri> GetImages(XElement gameNode)
    {
        return gameNode
                  .Descendants("boxart")
                  .Select(t => new Uri("http://thegamesdb.net/banners/" + (string)t.Attribute("thumb")));
```

Also change the

```
 Images = new Uri(GetImages(x))
```

to

```
Images = GetImages(x).ToList()
```

Comment: Yes maybe, im not sure how to collect all the image thumb links and show them in my LongListSelector.

Comment: Yeah, but i will need to make `public Uri Images { get; set; }` to `public List<Uri> Images { get; set; }` then right?. But the problem is, that im confused about how to add them to the list, because i can't do Images.Add(item) inside the linq select

Comment: Thanks :). But can you tell me how to show the images in my longlistselector also ?

Comment: Do you know how to get my longlistselector to show the images, i can't get it to show them, i think its because they are a in a list which is in a observable collection.